# i try to run my expo app in android emulator and i got stuck with Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: android, react-native, expo

i build app with expo and i would like to combine react-native-firebase
for analytics ,
for that i add the configure code and i want to open the app in android emulator
i run the command:npx expo run:android
and this is open the emulator and i get this ERROR
i dont know why please help!

i did everything.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uir5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7QTM.png)